# byobu - remove double bar

Tags: byobu

I love to use the [byobu tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29) to manage multiple ssh sessions. It works extremely well in Ubuntu, but when I [manually install it on Amazon Linux](http://blog.programster.org/2015/02/25/amazon-linux-install-byobu/) (and other distros) it often comes up with two bars rather than a single one as demonstrated in the screenshot below (selected in red):

[image]

How can I make it a single bar like the terminal below in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best solution was to run the following two commands:

```
sudo yum install tmux -y
byobu-select-backend
```

Then select the tmux backend instead of screen. This achieves the desired effect.